# Условие для скрытия подсказки jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть код который выводит подсказки, мне нужно, чтобы когда пользователь вводит и сервер ничего не выдал, скрыть #tips

```
function tips() {
    if($('#street').val().length>=1){

            var msg   = $('#street').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'request.php',
                    data: 'f=s&street='+msg+'&city='+$('#city').val(),
                    success: function(data) {

                    $('#tips').html(data);

                },
                    error:  function(xhr, str){
                            alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
                }
                }); 
        }
}
```

Пробовал вот так, но ничего не выходит, условие не работает

```
function tips() {
if($('#street').val().length>=1){

        var msg   = $('#street').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'request.php',
                data: 'f=s&street='+msg+'&city='+$('#city').val(),
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data != '') {
                $('#tips').html(data);
                    } else { $('#tips').fadeOut(350); }
            },
                error:  function(xhr, str){
                        alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
            }
            }); 
    }
```

}

Comment: А вы уверены, что `data` приходит пустой? Проверьте, когда сервер ничего не вернет, чему будет равна `data`?

Comment: оу, реально вы правы, оказывается приходит в ответе js скрипт, убрал его, спасибо за наводку, не углядел)